# Matlab doesn't see changes in java class when recompiled

Tags: java, matlab, class, matlab-java

I work with Matlab and try to launch java class from it.
So I add the path of java class to the `classpath.txt` in Matlab. Then I create an object of the java class `HelloWorld` and it works perfectly:

```
o = HelloWorld;
javaMethod('main', o);
```

However, when I change the code in `Helloworld`, Matlab doesn't see this: I need to restart Matlab to work with changed code of the `Helloworld`.

Is there a way to force Matlab to see changes in `Helloworld` without restarting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you tried the Matlab `clear classes` without success

If I take it from Yair Altman "*Undocumented Secrets of MATLAB-Java Programming*" :

Provided you didn't change the java class signature, you may be able to get away with it:

> > Java  classes  are  not  reloaded  automatically  by Matlab,  when  recompiled  outside 
> >     Matlab . to reload a modified Java class, we need to restart the JVM by restarting Matlab . 
> >     For classes placed on the dynamic classpath, you can try Matlab’s **`clear(‘java’)`** command, 
> >     while remembering its side effect of clearing all globals . However, this does not always work (e .g ., if the class signature has changed).

Apparently, if you feel like an expert Java programmer, there are potential workarounds:

> > Expert Java programmers can try to use Paul Milenkovic’s suggestion for a proxy classloader, as an alternative to restarting Matlab or clearing Java . as Dan Spielman explains, “the rough idea is that you create a classloader for your class, and then access it through the
> >     classloader . after you recompile, you kill the classloader and then create a new instance of it, which then reads the recompiled class” .

But the bottom line is:

> > In practice, **I suggest restarting Matlab after Java classes are recompiled**, even when this is not strictly necessary . It may save a lot of frustrating debugging and chasing down errors that only happen because Matlabkeeps an old class in memory.